# i2cset leaves the register value unchanged for OV2640 binocular camera module

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am trying to capture image using QYF-C01 OV2640 binocular camera module over beaglebone black wireless.

I am getting the I2C device address and register value properly, but can not configure I2C registers.

by trying

```
i2cset -y 2 0x30 0x12 0x80 w
```

it does not throw any error or warning, but it leaves the register unchanged.

by reading the register value using i2cget using following

```
i2cget -y 2 0x30 0x12 w
```

gives me 0x0000 which is unchanged.

I applied 3V3 using an external power supply, my PWDN pin is directly connected to GND and my RESETB pin is connected to one GPIO pin configured as an output pin. SDA and SCL pins are connected to SDA/SCL i2cbus 2 of my BBBW

I once changed the RESETB pin to LOW and then HIGH to reset all device control registers to default value before start setting the device control registers.

Comment: The question lacks half of needed information, like what Linux kernel you are using, does it have a driver for the camera sensor, where is the link to data sheet, did you read datasheet carefully and so on, so on.

Comment: Is there 'UU' when doing an i'2cdetect -y 2' at address 0x30.  If so, a Linux kernel module is using this address and just writing to it in user space can be tricky.

Comment: @0andriy  I am using  kernel version 4.9.82-ti-r102. Link to datasheet is https://cdn.datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/O/V/2/OV2640_OmniVisionTechnologie.pdf.

Comment: @vermaete no it is showing 30 at address 0x30

Comment: Does it show anything at 0x30?  So, just '--'.  If so, you have an I2C issue.  Could be some HW.  Have fun.

Comment: Have you tried to supply a _word_ value? Are you sure the device can operate with word transfers? What protocol you are using i2c or smbus?

Comment: @0andriy I am using Adafruit I2C library for i2c comminucation.

Comment: @vermaete it is showing '30' not '--' at 0x30.

Comment: You have to be consistent in your Q and comments. What are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the address is wrong.

The ov2640 datasheet says that the SCCB slave address is 0x60 by default. It can be changed in the SS_ID register.

You can get some code samples in the following file (for STM32):
https://myosuploads3.banggood.com/products/20190815/2019081501572110228.zip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30340576)